# Changing Context menu dealy time in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

The context menu control which is part of the toolkit when used inside the application , the delay before the menu appears is too long . It is much more than the normal delay observed in standard phone application. Is there any way to control this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no property or method available in the toolkit to define this duration. The source code seems to use `0.42` seconds. You could rebuild it by using a different value. (Although, you'll have to take a look at MS-PL and follow it.) The [license](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/license).

Comment: It doesnt seem like 0.42 sec. its about 2 seconds long.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. The release threshold *seems* to be set to 0.3 seconds and the context menu opening animation duration seems to be 0.42 seconds.(November release)

Comment: Basically, your "hold" gesture takes about one second, and once the context menu animation starts you have 0.3 seconds to stop the context menu from opening. So, yup, the toolkit's context menu needs you to hold for about 1.3 seconds to get the context menu open.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue. I had to turn off ZoomEnabled to get it to show up faster. Basically, with ZoomEnabled, you hold down the item the menu is linked to and it takes a good 2 seconds for it to simply appear. There is no animation going on, it just comes up instantly with everything else behind it zoomed back. It closes with an animation though. It's the opening animation that is totally broken. I guess that explains the 2 second delay. It's the animation delay except we're not seeing it.

Setting isZoomEnabled to false makes it work right again just that you lose the nifty animation and zooming.

```
 <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False"  >
                                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocalizedBinder}, ConverterParameter='Edit'}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditCommentGridVisibility}" Click="EditComment_Click" Tag="{Binding commentId}" />
                                                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource LocalizedBinder}, ConverterParameter='Remove'}" IsEnabled="{Binding RemoveCommentGridVisibility}" Click="DeleteComment_Click" Tag="{Binding commentId}" />
                                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
</toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```